# Dealing with .NET IDisposable objects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, idisposable, using-statement

I work in C#, and I've been pretty lax about using `using` blocks to declare objects that implement `IDisposable`, which you're apparently always supposed to do.  However, I don't see an easy way of knowing when I'm slipping up.  Visual Studio doesn't seem to indicate this in any way (am I just missing something?).  Am I just supposed to check help every time I declare anything, and gradually build up an encyclopedic memory for which objects are and which are not disposable?  Seems unnecessary, painful, and error-prone.

How do *you* handle this?

**EDIT:**

Looking at the related questions sidebar, I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785/setting-objects-to-nullnothing-after-use-in-dot-net) which made it clear that `Dispose()` is supposed to be called by the object's finalizer anyway.  So even if you never call it yourself, it should eventually happen, meaning you won't have a memory leak if you don't use `using` (which is what I suppose I was really worried about all along).  The only caveat is that the garbage collector doesn't know how much extra memory is being held by the object as unmanaged stuff, so it won't have an accurate idea how much memory will be freed by collecting the object.  This will result in less-ideal-than-usual performance by the garbage collector.

In short, it's not the end of the world if I miss a `using`.  I just wish something would generate at least a warning for it.

(Off-topic:  why is there no special markdown for linking to another question?)

**EDIT:**

Ok, fine, stop clamoring.  It's super duper all-fired [dramatic-chipmunk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1Y73sPHKxw)-level ***important*** to call `Dispose()` or we'll all *die*.

Now.  Given that, why is it so easy — hell, why is it even *allowed* — to do it wrong?  You have to go out of your way to do it right.  Doing it like everything else results in armageddon (apparently).  So much for encapsulation, huh?

[Stalks off, disgusted]

Comment: You won't find a single experienced .net programmer on the planet that will agree with you.  I don't mean to be melodramatic, but you really should pick up a good .Net book.

Comment: @Atario - you really should consider changing the accepted answer; frankly, Timwi is wrong - or at best, vastly over-simplifying things to the point where the two (wrong vs simplified) are very close.

Comment: You should call dispose as soon as you can, because it could release resources long before the next garbage collection is done.  If an object is using a resource on your server or desktop that would be released by Dispose(), do you really want to wait for the garbage collector to get around to it?

Answer (score 24):

FxCop *might* help (although it didn't spot a test I just fired at it); but yes: you are meant to check. `IDisposable` is simply such an important part of the system that you need to get into this habit. Using intellisense to look for `.D` is a good start (though not perfect).

However, it doesn't take long to familiarize yourself with types that need disposal; generally anything involving anything external (connection, file, database), for example.

ReSharper does the job too, offering a "put into using construct" option. It doesn't offer it as an error, though...

Of course, if you are unsure - *try* `using` it: the compiler will laugh mockingly at you if you are being paranoid:

```
using (int i = 5) {}

Error   1   'int': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

Answer (score 15):

If an object implements the `IDisposable` interface, then it is for a reason and you are meant to call it and it shouldn't be viewed as optional. The easiest way to do that is to use a `using` block.

`Dispose()` is not intended to only be called by an object's finalizer and, in fact, many objects will implement `Dispose()` but no finalizer (which is perfectly valid).

The whole idea behind the dispose pattern is that you are providing a somewhat deterministic way to release the **unmanaged** resources maintained by the object (or any object in it's inheritance chain). By not calling `Dispose()` properly you absolutely *can* run in to a memory leak (or any number of other issues).

The `Dispose()` method is not in any way related to a destructor. The closest you get to a destructor in .NET is a finalizer. The using statement doesn't do any deallocation...in fact calling `Dispose()` doesn't do any deallocation on the managed heap; it only releases unmanaged resources that had been allocated. The managed resources aren't truely deallocated until the GC runs and collects the memory space allocated to that object graph.

The best ways to determine if a class implements `IDisposable` are:

- IntelliSense (if it has a `Dispose()` or a `Close()` method)
- MSDN
- Reflector
- Compiler (if it doesn't implement `IDisposable` you get a compiler error)
- Common sense (if it *feels* like you should close/release the object after you're done, then you probably *should*)
- Semantics (if there is an `Open()`, there is probably a corresponding `Close()` that should be called)
- The compiler. Try placing it in a `using` statement. If it doesn't implement IDisposable, the compiler will generate an error.

Think of the dispose pattern as being all about scope lifetime management. You want to acquire the resource as last as possible, use as quickly as possibly, and release as soon as possible. The using statement helps to do this by ensuring that a call to `Dispose()` will be made even if there are exceptions.

Comment: The `.Dispose()` method *is* closely related to a destructor - the *finalizer* is what's different. You use `Dispose` for the same RAII-style deterministic deallocation that destructors are used in e.g. C++.

Answer (score 4):

This is why (IMHO) C++'s RAII is superior to .NET's `using` statement.

A lot of people said that `IDisposable` is only for un-managed resources, this is only true depending on how you define "resource". You can have a Read/Write lock implementing `IDisposable` and then the "resource" is the conceptual access to the code block. You can have an object that changes the cursor to hour-glass in the constructor and back to the previously saved value in `IDispose` and then the "resource" is the changed cursor. I would say that you use IDisposable when you want deterministic action to take place when leaving the scope no matter how the scope is left, but I have to admit that it's far less catchy than saying "it's for managing un-managed resource management".

See also the question about [why there's no RAII in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173670/why-is-there-no-raii-in-net).

Comment: Finalizers are for unmanaged resource management; IDisposable is for *deterministic* resource management. Typically for an unmanaged resource you want both - but it is fine to use IDisposable independently of unmanaged code.

Comment: You should NOT be using IDisposable to change the cursor or anything else. It is purely for freeing up unmanaged resources. You are "using it off-label", as Eric Lippert says. Read his comments at http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: In what way is a cursor not an "unmanaged resource"? Every control has one and when you change it you're contending with other people who want it otherwise changed and if it is "leaked" the cursor remains in the wrong state.

Answer (score 4):

> In short, it's not the end of the world if I miss a using. I just wish something would generate at least a warning for it.

The problem here is that you can't always deal with an IDisposable by just wrapping it up in a `using` block. Sometimes you need the object to hang around for a bit longer. In which case you will have to call its `Dispose` method explicitly yourself.

A good example of this is where a [class uses a private EventWaitHandle (or an AutoResetEvent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659840/do-i-need-to-dispose-or-close-an-eventwaithandle) to communicate between two threads and you want to Dispose of the WaitHandle once the thread is finished.

So it isn't as simple as some tool just checking that you only create IDisposable objects within a `using` block.

Answer (score 3):

@Atario, not only the accepted answer is wrong, your own edit is as well. Imagine the following situation (*that actually occurred* in one CTP of Visual Studio 2005):

For drawing graphics, you create pens without disposing them. Pens don't require a lot of memory but they use a GDI+ handle internally. If you don't dispose the pen, the GDI+ handle will not be released. If your application isn't memory intensive, quite some time can pass without the GC being called. However, the number of available GDI+ handles is restricted and soon enough, when you try to create a new pen, the operation will fail.

In fact, in Visual Studio 2005 CTP, if you used the application long enough, all fonts would suddenly switch to “System”.

This is precisely why it's **not enough** to rely on the GC for disposing. The memory usage doesn't necessarily corelate with the number of unmanaged resources that you acquire (and don't release). Therefore, these resoures may be exhausted long before the GC is called.

Additionally, there's of course the whole aspects of side-effects that these resources may have (such as access locks) that prevent other applications from working properly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have anything to add to the general use of Using blocks but just wanted to add an exception to the rule:

Any object that implements IDisposable apparently should not throw an exception during its Dispose() method. This worked perfectly until WCF (there may be others), and it's now possible that an exception is thrown by a WCF channel during Dispose(). If this happens when it's used in a Using block, this causes issues, and requires the implementation of exception handling. This obviously requires more knowledge of the inner workings, which is why Microsoft now recommends not using WCF channels in Using blocks (sorry could not find link, but plenty other results in Google), even though it implements IDisposable.. Just to make things more complicated!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither FxCop or StyleCop seem to warn on this.  As other commenters have mentioned, it is usually quite important to make sure to call dispose.  If I'm not sure, I always check the Object Browser (Ctrl+Alt+J) to look at the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

I use using blocks primarily for this scenario:

I'm consuming some external object (usually an IDisposable wrapped COM object in my case).  The state of the object itself may cause it to throw an exception or how it affects my code may cause me to throw an exception, and perhaps in many different places.  In general, I trust no code outside of my current method to behave itself.

For the sake of argument, lets say I have 11 exit points to my method, 10 of which are inside this using block and 1 after it (which can be typical in some library code I've written).

Since the object is automatically disposed of when exiting the using block, I don't need to have 10 different .Dispose() calls--it just happens.  This results in cleaner code, since it is now less cluttered with dispose calls (~10 fewer lines of code in this case).

There is also less risk of introducing IDisposable leak bugs (which can be time consuming to find) by somebody altering the code after me if they forget to call dispose, because it isn't necessary with a using block.

Answer (score 0):

Like Fxcop (to which they're related), the code analysis tools in VS (if you have one of the higher-up editions) will find these cases too.

Comment: Actually, I've just tried both FxCop and the VSTS analysis; neither spotted a missed "using" in a trivial test...

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the "using" blocks. For most objects, it doesn't make a big difference however I encountered a recent issue where I implemented an ActiveX control in a class and in didn't clean up gracefully unless the Dispose was called correctly. The bottom line is even if it doesn't seem to make much of a difference, try to do it correctly because some time it will make a difference.

Comment: That's a classic workaround for problems with COM interop / ActiveX interop. It's certainly an argument for tidying up those objects with `using`. It's not necessarily an argument for tidying up **every** object with `using`

Comment: I don't know if I would call it a "workaround"; it is more of cleaning up unmanaged resources that may crash or otherwise cause problems. As far as "an argument for tidying up every object" - my opinion is you should always .Dispose of object implementing IDisposable unless there is a very good reason otherwise and the "using" block is typically the easiest mechanism for doing so. It's not really an argument, just my opinion. Others, e.g. Scott Dorman's answer, have made more of an attempt at an argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush/1930393#1930393) the [CodeRush add-in](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) will detect and flag when local IDisposable variables aren't cleaned up, in real-time, as you type.

Could meet you halfway on your quest.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not getting the point of your question. Thanks to the garbage collector, memory leaks are close to impossible to occur. However, you need some robust logic.

I use to create `IDisposable` classes like this:

```
public MyClass: IDisposable
{

    private bool _disposed = false;

    //Destructor
    ~MyClass()
    { Dispose(false); }

    public void Dispose()
    { Dispose(true); }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        /* actions to always perform */

        if (disposing) { /* actions to be performed when Dispose() is called */ }

        _disposed=true;
}
```

Now, even if you miss to use `using` statement, the object will be eventually garbage-collected and proper destruction logic is executed. You may stop threads, end connections, save data, whatever you need (in [this example](http://logbus-ng.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/logbus-ng/trunk/logbus-core/It.Unina.Dis.Logbus/Clients/ClientBase.cs?revision=849&view=markup), I unsubscribe from a remote service and perform a remote delete call if needed)

[Edit] obviously, calling Dispose as soon as possible helps application performance, and **is** a good practice. But, thanks to my example, if you forget to call Dispose it will be eventually called and the object is cleaned up.

Comment: -1 for the less-than-safe linked example. the code has at least 2 problems - 1) managed objects are being accessed from the finalizer thread because it does not distinguish between proper disposable and finalization 2) it is not thread safe because the dispose method does not atomically test and set the disposed flag (and due to problem #1 the code has been made multithreaded since the finalizer runs on its own thread)

Comment: Yes. In the code you post here in your answer, you have a check `if(disposing) { }` but in the code you linked to it makes no such check. So it does the same thing whether it was called by the programmer properly disposing it or whether it was called by the garbage collector invoking the finalizer.

Comment: In fact it was the programmer's intention (mine!) to do the same in both cases. That file invokes a web service to terminate the subscription to a UDP message pump before it timeouts. I linked the code not to display an example of the *if* statement mentioned, but to show how the finalizer should be used to dispose of resources at business logic level. You mentioned managed objects accessed from finalizer thread: is something else wrong with it rather than concurrency?

Comment: I looked at your example again. Ignoring the potential crash due to the finalizer race condition, there is another key problem. The `ClientBase` class does not manage any native resources (e.g. GDI handle, socket, etc). The sole purpose of finalizers is to free native resources. If you aren't freeing native resources, you aren't supposed to have a finalizer. The `ChannelManager` may own native resources, and therefore the `ChannelManager` may implement a finalizer. But the `ClientBase` does not directly own native resources and thus should not implement a finalizer.

Comment: Microsoft's reasoning for why you shouldn't touch managed objects in the finalizer is explained briefly here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddae83kx.aspx  Joe Duffy's excellent article is what clarified these important points for me. http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I realized that you wanted me to address point #2. In your `Dispose()` you check for `if(Disposed)` at the beginning of your method. Then later after some cleanup actions, you set the `Disposed` flag to `true`. During the time that the Dispose method is running on one thread, it could be invoked again on another thread. If the "first" thread is still working on the cleanup, then the `Disposed` flag will be false and the "second" thread will also begin the clean up actions. If you can guarantee that you only call `Dispose` from one thread, then you are fine.