# Do I need to Dispose() or Close() an EventWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

If I am using `EventWaitHandle` (or `AutoResetEvent`, `ManualResetEvent`) to synchronise between threads then do I need to call the `Close()` or `Dispose()` methods on that event handle when I am done with it?

`EventWaitHandle` inherits from `WaitHandle`, which implements `IDisposable`. And FxCop complains if I don't implement `IDisposable` on any class that contains an `EventWaitHandle`. So this suggests that I do need to call it.

However none of these MSDN usage examples call `Dispose()` or `Close()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(VS.80).aspx

Is this just an example of Microsoft ignoring their own advice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The disposable resource of an `EventWaitHandle` is actually a `SafeHandle` (wrapped in a `SafeWaitHandle`). `SafeHandle` implements a finalizer, which eventually makes sure the necessary resource is release, so it should be safe to let the garbage collector / finalizer thread handle it *in this case*.

However, it is always a good idea to explicitly call `Dispose()` when the resource is no longer needed.

The threading chapter in [C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) states

> This practice is (arguably) acceptable
>   with wait handles because they have a
>   light OS burden (asynchronous
>   delegates rely on exactly this mechanism
>   to release their `IAsyncResult`'s wait
>   handle).

Comment: I'd argue that letting the GC collect it is quite undesirable. Leaving the work to the Finalizer thread is just bad practice. There is but a single finalizer thread and causing it to do more than it really should is not good.  If the thread gets blocked, your app is hung.  If an exception is thrown on the finalizer thread, your AppDomain crashes. Having the proper dispose pattern guarantees that GC.SuppressFinalize() is called thus suppressing finalization of this object.  I have an example of implementing IDisposable - http://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html

Comment: I agree and that's why I state that you should explicitly call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to dispose them explicitly. Close() is more appropriate for them as it does call Dispose().

Answer (score 2):

Class definitions from MSDN:

```
public class EventWaitHandle : WaitHandle
public abstract class WaitHandle : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
```

So yes you must as WaitHandle is IDisposable.  FxCop would find this as a rule violation if you didn't.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but why don't the MSDN usage examples call Close() or Dispose()?
Is this just Microsoft not following their own advice?

Comment: I'd guess it's 50% not following their own advice, and 50% trying to keep the examples as brief as possible..  with a side dish of the folks writing the examples (not the core sdk developers) not knowing better.

Comment: @PeterDrier The examples use static wait handles.

Answer (score 0):

Close method disposes it internally.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.dispose?view=net-6.0):

> Always call Close or Dispose() before you release your last reference to the WaitHandle. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed.

So, as they inherit `WaitHandle`, in my opinion, you should dispose the `EventWaitHandle` (or `AutoResetEvent`, `ManualResetEvent`) too