# Memory leak in anonymous function

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, closures, resharper

**TLDR;**

Non-trivial memory leak, can be seen easily in Resharper. See minimal example below.

---

I'm seeing a memory leak in the following program but failing to see why.

The program sends pings to a number of hosts asynchronously and determines if at least one is ok. To do that, a method (`SendPing()`) that runs these async operations is repeatedly called which runs them in a background thread (it doesn't have to, but in the actual application `SendPing()` will be called by the main UI thread which shouldn't be blocked).

The task seems pretty trivial but I think the leak occurs due to the way I create lambdas inside the `SendPing()` method. The program can be changed to not use lambdas but I'm more interested in understanding what causes the leak here.

```
public class Program
{

    static string[] hosts = { "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com" };

    static void SendPing()
    {
        int numSucceeded = 0;
        ManualResetEvent alldone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        ManualResetEvent[] handles = new ManualResetEvent[hosts.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
            handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            numSucceeded = 0;
            Action<int, bool> onComplete = (hostIdx, succeeded) =>
            {
                if (succeeded) Interlocked.Increment(ref numSucceeded);
                handles[hostIdx].Set();
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
                SendPing(i, onComplete);

            ManualResetEvent.WaitAll(handles);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded " + numSucceeded);
            BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            alldone.Set();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        alldone.WaitOne();
        worker.Dispose();
    }

    static void SendPing(int hostIdx, Action<int, bool> onComplete)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        pingSender.PingCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            bool succeeded = args.Error == null && !args.Cancelled && args.Reply != null && args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            onComplete(hostIdx, succeeded);
            Ping p = sender as Ping;
            p.Dispose();
        };

        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
        pingSender.SendAsync(hosts[hostIdx], 2000, buffer, options, hostIdx);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send ping " + i);
            SendPing();
        }
    }
}
```

Resharper shows the leaks are due to uncollected closure objects (`c__DisplayClass...`).

[image]
[image]

From what I understand, there shouldn't be a leak because there are no circular references (as far as I see) and therefore GC should take of the leaks. I also call `Dispose` to release the thread (bgw) + sockets (`Ping` object) promptly. (Even if I didn't GC will clean them up eventually, won't it?)

### **Suggested changes from comments**

- Remove event handles before Disposing
- Dispose `ManualResetEvent`

**But the leak is still there!**

Changed program:

```
public class Program
{

    static string[] hosts = { "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com" };

    static void SendPing()
    {
        int numSucceeded = 0;
        ManualResetEvent alldone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (sender, args) =>
        {
            ManualResetEvent[] handles = new ManualResetEvent[hosts.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
                handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            numSucceeded = 0;
            Action<int, bool> onComplete = (hostIdx, succeeded) =>
            {
                if (succeeded) Interlocked.Increment(ref numSucceeded);
                handles[hostIdx].Set();
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
                SendPing(i, onComplete);

            ManualResetEvent.WaitAll(handles);
            foreach (var handle in handles)
                handle.Close();

        };

        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler completed = (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded " + numSucceeded);
            BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            alldone.Set();
        };

        worker.DoWork += doWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += completed;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        alldone.WaitOne();
        worker.DoWork -= doWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= completed;
        worker.Dispose();
    }

    static void SendPing(int hostIdx, Action<int, bool> onComplete)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingCompletedEventHandler completed = null;
        completed = (sender, args) =>
        {
            bool succeeded = args.Error == null && !args.Cancelled && args.Reply != null && args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            onComplete(hostIdx, succeeded);
            Ping p = sender as Ping;
            p.PingCompleted -= completed;
            p.Dispose();
        };

        pingSender.PingCompleted += completed;

        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
        pingSender.SendAsync(hosts[hostIdx], 2000, buffer, options, hostIdx);
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send ping " + i);
            SendPing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using *ping.SendPingAsync* and *Task.WhenAll* can simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks (I wasn't aware of `SendPingAsync`) but I have to use .NET 3 for this application so can't have `Task`s

Comment: `worker.RunWorkerCompleted` and `worker.DoWork` are your memory leaks. You should unsubscribe from those events prior to disposing, but because you have them as lambda expressions, it makes it a little more difficult. `Dispose` tells the object to clean up, however you still have active references to the `worker` object which can't be released, and the GC won't collect them. Personally I think lambda handlers were a bad choice from the C# spec team. `PingCompleted` has the same issue.

Comment: @RonBeyer But why? Won't the event handler references be discarded when the worker gets collected (once the worker thread is disposed)?

Comment: No, GC won't automatically disconnect event handlers, its up to you to do that prior to disposing the object.

Comment: Thanks but still it doesn't seem to fix the leak.. I've added the modified program at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory leak. dotMemory that you use analyzes the snapshots and indeed, in the context of one snapshot the auto-generated class created by the compiler for the completed event handler will still be in memory. Rewrite your main application like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send ping " + i);
        SendPing();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("All done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Run the profiler, allow the application to reach the point where it outputs "All done", wait a few seconds and take a new snapshot. You will see there is no longer any memory leak.

It is worth mentioning that the class generated by the compiler for the PingCompleted event handler (that is `c_DisplayClass6`) will linger in memory after the method `static void SendPing(int hostIdx, Action<int, bool> onComplete)` exits. What happens there is that when `pingSender.PingCompleted += (sender, args) =>...` is executed the `pingSender` instance will take a reference to `c_DisplayClass6`. During the call to `pingSender.SendAsync`, the framework will retain a reference to `pingSender` in order to deal with running the async method and its completion. The async method you initiate by calling `pingSender.SendAsync` still runs when method SendPing exits. Because of that `pingSender` will survive a little while longer, hence `c_DisplayClass6` will survive a little while longer too. However, after the `pingSender.SendAsync` operation completes, the framework will release its references to `pingSender`. At this point both `pingSender` and `c_DisplayClass6` become garbage collectable and eventually the garbage collector will collect them. You can see this if you take a last snapshot like I was mentioning above. In that snapshot dotMemory will no longer detect a leak.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. however, after waiting few minutes on ReadLine() I still don't see a decline in the 'Unmanaged Memory' as shown in dotMemory. May be I'll leave it overnight to see when they get collected! To clarify, I don't call Dispose explicitly in the program but when the program is at the ReadLine() statement above, as per your explanation I'm assuming the remaining memory will be cleaned up by GC.

Comment: We are talking about separate things now. Managed memory leaks and high usage of native memory are different things. I was addressing your original question - that about memory leaks and I was explaining that you do not really have event handler leaks. To get a feel about how much native memory the system will use comment in the Main method the call to SendPing. You are still going to have a lot of native memory used on top of the native memory even when you basically do nothing much.

Answer (score 1):

ManualResetEvent implements Dispose(). You are instantiating a number of ManualResetEvents and never calling dispose.

When an object implements dispose you need to call it.  If you do not call it, there'll quite likely be memory leaks.  You should use using statements, and try finally to dispose objects  Simarly you should also have a using statement around Ping.

EDIT: This may be useful....

[When should a ManualResetEvent be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513805/when-should-a-manualresetevent-be-disposed)

EDIT: As stated here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2(v=vs.110).aspx

> When you create objects that include unmanaged resources, you must
>   explicitly release those resources when you finish using them in your
>   app.

EDIT: As stated here...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.100).aspx

> Dispose() Releases all resources used by the current instance of the
>   WaitHandle class. (Inherited from WaitHandle.)

The ManualResetEvent has unmanaged resources associated with it, which is fairly typical of most of the classes in the .NET Framework libraries which implements IDisposable.

EDIT: Try using this...

```
public class Program
{
    static string[] hosts = { "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com" };

    static void SendPing()
    {
        int numSucceeded = 0;
        using (ManualResetEvent alldone = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = null;
            ManualResetEvent[] handles = null;
            try
            {
                worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    handles = new ManualResetEvent[hosts.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
                        handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                    numSucceeded = 0;
                    Action<int, bool> onComplete = (hostIdx, succeeded) =>
                    {
                        if (succeeded) Interlocked.Increment(ref numSucceeded);
                        handles[hostIdx].Set();
                    };

                    for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Length; i++)
                        SendPing(i, onComplete);

                    ManualResetEvent.WaitAll(handles);
                    foreach (var handle in handles)
                        handle.Close();

                };

                RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler completed = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Succeeded " + numSucceeded);
                    BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                    alldone.Set();
                };

                worker.DoWork += doWork;
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += completed;

                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
                alldone.WaitOne();
                worker.DoWork -= doWork;
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= completed;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handles != null)
                {
                    foreach (var handle in handles)
                        handle.Dispose();
                }
                if (worker != null)
                    worker.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    static void SendPing(int hostIdx, Action<int, bool> onComplete)
    {
        using (Ping pingSender = new Ping())
        {
            PingCompletedEventHandler completed = null;
            completed = (sender, args) =>
            {
                bool succeeded = args.Error == null && !args.Cancelled && args.Reply != null && args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
                onComplete(hostIdx, succeeded);
                Ping p = sender as Ping;
                p.PingCompleted -= completed;
                p.Dispose();
            };

            pingSender.PingCompleted += completed;

            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
            pingSender.SendAsync(hosts[hostIdx], 2000, buffer, options, hostIdx);
        }
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send ping " + i);
            SendPing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still has a memory leak because of the lambda event handlers. Dispose/using won't fix that.

Comment: Even if Dispose isn't called GC collects them eventually doesn't it? What I'm seeing is a consistent memory growth...

Comment: I've added edits in response to your comment.  Furthermore I'd add basically good .NET developers look up the documentation for every class they instantiate and if the class implements Dispose they make sure Dispose is called.  Failing to do so can only cause issues

Comment: @ubi basically yes.... once the application is closed, you could wait hours or days otherwise and in the meantime your application will leak memory

Comment: @ubi if you're an ASP.NET developer, you probably think the GC is far more aggressive than it actually is.  In ASP.NET every request is handled in it's own thread, at the end of the request the thread is terminated and the GC does aggressively collect objects associated with a terminated thread, as such undisposed resources are collected quickly.  If your application has threads with indefinitely long life times you will find the GC behaves very differently and will seem to leak memory.