# Is it necessary to close / dispose SafeHandles

Tags: c#

I'm using SafeHandles in my code and noticed they have Close and Dispose methods.

This got me wondering whether or not SafeHandles were handled by the garbage collector and disposed of after use.

For example if I got a handle like this, would I need to call the .Dispose or .Close method after I was finished using it.

```
var process Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];

var handle = process.SafeHandle;
```

Comment: There´s usually a reason why one would implement `IDisposable`. So rely on this and dispose what *might* be disposable. Even if there´s currently no need because the class does not have any unmanaged ressources, this may change in the future.

Comment: I would say so. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dispose

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659840/do-i-need-to-dispose-or-close-an-eventwaithandle

Comment: The pattern is a bit murky here, GetProcessBy___() doesn't look like you allocate a resource. But you do, I would worry about `process` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `Close` or `Dispose` method allows the `resources` to be `freed`. This might not happen immediately if other threads are using the same instance of the safe handle, but will happen as soon as that is no longer the case. Although most classes using `SafeHandle` do not need to provide a `finalizer`, this is sometimes necessary (for example, to flush out file buffers or to write some data back into memory). In this case, they can provide a `finalizer` that is guaranteed to run before the `SafeHandle` critical `finalizer` runs.

Always `call` the `Close` or `Dispose` method before you release your last reference to the `SafeHandle` object. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the `SafeHandle` object's `Finalize method`.

> You should never `explicitly call` the `Dispose method` with the disposing `parameter` set to `false`

[See the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Always call the Close or Dispose method before you release your last
>   reference to the SafeHandle object. Otherwise, the resources it is
>   using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the
>   SafeHandle object's Finalize method.