# Best way to prettify an XmlDocument (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Let's say I have a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` whose `InnerXml` is:

`<comedians><act id="1" type="single" name="Harold Lloyd"/><act id="2" type="duo" name="Laurel and Hardy"><member>Stan Laurel</member><member>Oliver Hardy</member></act></comedians>`

I'd like to format it thusly, with newlines and whitespace added:

```
<comedians>
    <act id="1" type="single" name="Harold Lloyd"/>
    <act id="2" type="duo" name="Laurel and Hardy">
        <member>Stan Laurel</member>
        <member>Oliver Hardy</member>
    </act>
</comedians>
```

I looked in the `XmlDocument` class for some prettifying method, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Little edit: the best way to do it in C# is probably also the best way in VB.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you can use `XmlDocument.Save(Stream)` and pass any Stream as target to receive the xml content. Including a "memory-only" `StringWriter` as below:

```
string xml = "<myXML>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    doc.Save(sw);
    Console.Write(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
}
```

Update: using block

Comment: You've tested that? It indents? Also -1 for no using blocks.

Comment: @Eduardo: you're correct that doc.Save indents. I'll remove the downvote for that. doc.WriteTo does not. And you want using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {doc.Save(sw); Consolw.Write(sw.ToString());}

Comment: Weird, I tried both .WriteTo and .Save to a StringWriter, and both times the StringBuilder.ToString() isn't indented.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Galloway posted an answer and deleted it, but it was actually the best option for me. It went somewhat like this:

```
StringBuilder Prettify(XmlDocument xdoc)
{
    StringBuilder myBuf = new StringBuilder();
    XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(myBuf));
    myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xdoc.Save(myWriter);
    return myBuf;
}
```

No need to create a `XmlWriterSettings` object.

Comment: Yes, but he was wrong for two other reasons, which is why he deleted it. Don't use XmlTextWriter. Also, you need using blocks. It turns out that XmlDocument.Save by itself is all you need for indentation.

Comment: What, exactly, happens if I don't use using?

Comment: If you don't either use a using block or otherwise call .Dispose() on an object that implements IDisposable then you may leak memory, handles, etc. And a little village somewhere catches fire.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254969/dealing-with-net-idisposable-objects or google IDisposable - and don't be jaded by the "but it gets called by the finalizer anyways' propaganda.

Answer (score -3):

Trying to prettify XML is like putting lipstick on a pig :) It still ain't gonna be pretty.

Why are you trying to prettify it? If it is for editing purposes, Visual Studio does a pretty good job of presenting it in readable form. If it is for a user, then they may prefer to just open up in their preferred editor or explorer.

Comment: This habit to ask people why they want to do something is just detestable.
We are  here to answer questions and provide solutions. Not to question why people want to do something.