# Detecting attached event handlers for garbage collection

Tags: .net, event-handling, garbage-collection

I'm inheriting an existing application that has a number of memory holes. I suspect they are caused by event handlers that are subscribed but never released. What tools or resources can I use to help identify the objects that are being held on to even after they have gone out of scope because of an open event handler?

Comment: Not directly your answer but I suggest you read this: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/07/07/circulareventrefs

Comment: WinDbg + psscor2 / SOS gives you awesome commands like !GCWhere, !FindRoots !HandleCLRN, !GCRoot, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success using [redgate's ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to chase down similar issues.  It's not an inexpensive product, but in my experience it's proven very useful and been worth the cost.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains also has a memory profiler: [dotTrace Memory](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). I've got it but haven't used it enough to make a recommendation. It's not free either (unless you win a license at a user's group). :)

I'd also check to insure that all objects whose classes implement IDisposable are properly disposed. A `using` block will insure this even if an exception occurs. While that involves unmanaged resources rather than memory, in practice there may be little difference.

See also [Detecting "leaked" IDisposable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737056/detecting-leaked-idisposable-objects), which mentions multiple memory profilers.