# Cannot access a disposed object 'RichTextBox'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, serial-port, richtextbox

A program I developed in Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 using c# has been generating the following error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19853155/code%20error%2001.jpg

I have kind of isolated the issue down to this segment of code:

```
if (gui.rawLogLSM.InvokeRequired)
{
    gui.rawLogLSM.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        gui.rawLogLSM.AppendText(t.ToString()); 
        gui.rawLogLSM.ScrollToCaret();
    }));
}
else
{
    gui.rawLogLSM.AppendText(t.ToString());
    gui.rawLogLSM.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Basically in this segment of code, I am reading raw data from a serial port, and printing it into a text box, byte by byte. (I can't read the whole buffer in at a time, as that invalidates what we're doing for the project).

I am not wholly sure how this error is actually generated or under what conditions. The error has only presented itself when a co-worker is using the application in my absence, and I've been unable to recreate the error.

The error from info from the exception comes up in form of a message box due to me having a try/catch around a larger block of code, within which the above code is apart of.

So my question is mostly, how can I solve this error or what should I be doing to force said error to show itself?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This happens when you close the window while the device is still sending data.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the invoke is on a different thread and the exception is thrown when trying to invoke the textbox while another thread has disposed the textbox(on form close maybe?)? If this is because the textbox is disposed on different thread, one solution would be to surround AppendText and ScrollToCaret inside the invoke with try/catch and swallow that specific error.

Comment: problem is the form never closes, and when it does, the entire program shuts down completely. I'll try a try/catch on those two lines and see what we get.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is pretty straightforward: your rich text box is being disposed before you access it. Unfortunately, these can be very nasty to track down, especially if you can't reproduce it.

Do a sanity check and make sure that the RTB is indeed created before the Append()'ing code is called, but my gut tells me you'd get constant errors if it wasn't.

To me, the first step is to reliably reproduce it. Use your coworker's machine, have them demonstrate what they were doing when the error popped up, ensure the framework and application versions are the same, etc etc.

Once you can reproduce it, you'll have to find WHERE the object is disposed. You can do it manually by right-clicking a call to the dispose and choosing "show all references". Set breakpoints on each of them, or use some other monitoring scheme (like a log, which can be used to watch programs on non-development machines). Remember that the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class is useful for seeing what called Dispose.

There are also [tools that monitor memory usage and disposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737056/detecting-leaked-idisposable-objects) that can help you out.

I'd also recommend turning debug mode on and giving your coworker the debug-enabled executable and the symbol file (pdb) as this may help track the problem.

Other things to check are race conditions, simultaneous/cross-thread access, exceptions in other threads that may be swallowed by the CLR, only to fudge up your code later on, and make sure you end all threads before you close your form. If you don't, weird stuff can happen. At best, your program will continue to hang in memory, invisible to all but task manager. Worse, you can pop up random error dialogs "out of the blue" as something finally fails. In your case, it might be failing immediately.