# RAII-Wrapper for .NET?

Tags: .net, raii

Is it theoretically possible to create a RAII-Wrapper for .NET? As a long time C++ programmer I hate to manage object lifetime myself again. The Dispose-Pattern is IMHO nothing but a bad joke compared to the ease of use of RAII, especially as it forces the user to handle the implementation detail (Dispose) of an object and the class to become IDisplosable itself…

Comment: "I hate to manage object lifetime myself again", what is your concern?  The IDisplosable interface should be an extremely rare case. In the same area as when RAII is not achievable.

Comment: Even the most basic Timer is IDisposable…

Comment: Which Timer class are you thinking about? Many classes are IDisposable, not necessarily meaning you need to write cleanup code for it.

Comment: I'm using System.Timers.Timer which forces the surrounding class to be IDisposable - VS even generates a warning about leaking resources if I don't handle the dispose of the timer…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no RAII in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173670/why-is-there-no-raii-in-net)

Comment: "I'm creating a Plugin-based system"  <curious>How would you force the plugins to use RAII?</curious>

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: the abstract base class (yes, not interface) would be RAII => C++ answer: by deleting the object / be letting the object go out of scope anything is released seamlessly… As IDisposable is an implementation detail it's IMHO not usable as a base class.

Comment: @Joe: I'm not asking why there is no RAII - I'm aware of the reasons, though I don't agree with them in conjunction with stack-based objects (aka. .NET-structs). I'm asking if there is any way around that limitation, e.g. a C++/CLI class…

Comment: @MFH: This is not a language problem -- this is a restriction imposed by the .NET runtime.  There is nothing you can do in managed code to avoid this.  Use IDisposable: it exists for this very reason.

Comment: @Joe: so my base class has to be IDisposable cause it may happen that a plugin is IDisposable?

Comment: @Joe: Even with the framework as it is, vb.net and C# could provide much better support for RAII than they presently do.  Among other things, since the most common thing for a `Dispose` method to do is call `Dispose` on certain fields if they aren't null, a compiler could allow fields to be tagged to indicate that they require such cleanup, and then automatically implement `IDisposable.Dispose` so as to perform it.  Having one line of code declare a variable and specify that it needs cleanup, seems much cleaner than requiring declaration and cleanup to be in different parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose is only for unmanaged resources. For managed resources, you have to do nothing since the garbage collector takes care of it (and doesn't even allow you to do deterministic release of resources anyway).

So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: That not entirely true, as even basic Timers force you to handle Dispose… I'm creating a Plugin-based system and as there is no automatic way to handle IDisposable it seems like I'll have to make my public Interface disposable as otherwise I may leak resources that are acquired by the plugins - which may not even be written be me.

Comment: @MFH Why do you relate this to RAII?

Comment: Because with RAII I don't have to care about Disposing, it's done as soon as the object goes out of scope. Furthermore due to RAII the consumer of a class doesn't have to handle the cleanup of the object. If I write a .NET-class that contains a Timer that class has to be disposeable itself and has to dispose that Timer whereas with RAII I just contain the Timer and as soon as my object goes out of scope it's destructor is automatically called which cleans up the resources…

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Sharing/Taking Care of IDisposable objects can be problematic indeed.